# Font not found, vuejs build

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, build, core-ui

I have in my `config/index.js`:

```
...
build: {
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/client.html'),
    assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '',
...
```

My App.vue:

```
<style lang="scss">
  /* Import Font Awesome Icons Set */
  $fa-font-path: '~font-awesome/fonts/';
  @import '~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss';
  ...
</style>
```

When in dev mode it's all right, no missing assets etc..., everything is fine.

But when I build the project the fonts path becomes:

> dist/static/css/static/fonts/font

And this results in a 404 error for the given asset, since I have no folders inside ths `css` and I have no idea why is doing this.

Please note that I don't want this to be in the root, e.g:

```
assetsPublicPath: '/', // <-- don't want this since the project it's going to be in a subfolder
```

If you guys think that are some scripts missing for a better/less
equivocating answer please tell me and I edit it to include them.

Answer (score 1):

Remove whatever you have posted in `App.vue` pertaining to `Font Awesome`.

Inside of `main.js` or `app.js`, do the following. It should start to build nicely.

### main.js / app.js

```
require('font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss')
```